Building a spam detector in python without the use of third party libraries
def spam_detection(email):
    with open('email.txt', 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
        contents = f.read()

    spam_keywords = ["account has been hacked", "urgent", "save on", "big deals","click this link","win","claim your prize"," !", " .", "lucky winner", "click here",]   

    if any(keyword in contents for keyword in spam_keywords):
        return "spam"

    return "ham"

result = spam_detection('email.txt')
print(result)

#this is my code

I'm trying to flag all emails with the given keywords in the contents and subjects of any given email.

Ok. Do you have a question of some kind? Stack Overflow is a Q&A site and it is not immediately obvious what kind of answer to your post you would like to get.

Classical spam detectors are often based on the machine learning approach of Support Vector Machines (SVMs). You may find, for example, reading this article helpful as an introduction to the subject. If you want to build your own SVM from scratch in Python rather than using one from a library, you may find, for example, this article helpful.

Also note that, while you pass the email parameter to your spam_detection() function, you do not actually use it. Instead, 'email.txt' is hard-coded in the line with open('email.txt', 'r', errors='ignore') as f. Furthermore, you are using both single quotes (') and double quotes (") for string literals. This is not a problem per se, but I would consider it as bad style.
